# How to load a notebook from within jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

If I run `jupyter notebook` it shows me a list of files in the current directory. However I can't see any way to change directory or generally to open a jupyter notebook stored on my hard drive. I can open one from the command line with:

```
jupyter notebook dream.ipynb
```

Is there any way to open an existing notebook that isn't in the current directory from jupyter notebook itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jupyter notebook` consider the current directory from where it is run as the root folder. I guess the only way you can do that is by firing `jupyter notebook` on root directory itself. This way you can access every folder inside the root folder.

Or if you know beforehand where your required notebook is lying you can navigate to that directory and run `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Oh wow. The ability to go up a directory seems like an important missing feature.

Comment: yes it is disturbing sometimes. There might be other reason to do so, though.

Comment: I was just going to file that issue :)